# Indexing data in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have imported a lot of data from an excel spreadsheet so that I have a 1x27 matrix.

I have imported data from excel using this

```
filename = 'for_matlab.xlsx';
sheet = 27;
xlRange = 'A1:G6';
all_data = {};

for i=1:sheet,
    all_data{i} = xlsread(filename, i, xlRange);
end
```

However each element of this all_data matrix (which is 1x27) contains my data but I'm having trouble accessing individual elements.

i.e.

```
all_data{1}
```

Will give me the entire matrix but I need to perform multiplications on individual elements of this data

also

```
all_data(1)
```

just gives '5x6 double', i.e. the matrix dimensions.

Does anybody know how I can  divide all elements of each row by the third element in each row and do this for all of my 'sub-matrices' (for want of a better word)

Comment: It's not clear what format your data are in. Perhaps you can make a small mock data set and post some code to receate it e.g. `{{[1 2; 3 4], [5, 6; 7, 8]}, {[1 2; 3 4], [5, 6; 7, 8]}}`. Just make sure to try include all features such as if matrices sizes can differ etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `all_data` is a cell array and that each cell contains a matrix (with at least three columns):

```
result = cellfun(@(x) bsxfun(@rdivide, x, x(:,3)), all_data, 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing terminology in matlab. what you have is 1x27 **CELLS** each of them containing a matrix. 
If you access `all_data{1}` it will give you the whole matrix stored in the first cell. 
If you want to access the elemets of that matrix then you need to do: `all_data{1}(2,4)`. This example access the 2,4 element of the matrix in the first cell.

Definitely Luis Mendo has solved you problem, but be aware of the differences of Cells and matrixes in Matlab!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found the answer now.

Basically you have to use both types of brackets because the data types are different

i.e. all_data{1}(1:4) or something like that anyway.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried Luis Mendo's solution? It will solve your entire problem in one line!

Comment: Hi there. First, you shoudl try Luis's answer, it will be usefull for you. Then You shoudl be aware of what you are doing when indexing cells and matrixs in matlab, else you will come again with a similar problem in the future, adn we dont want you to have problems! Last but not least, StackOVerflow is a question and answer place where you SHOULD accept the answers that suit your questio (clicking the tick next to  it). This is not a forum and it doesnt work lite that! Cheers and good luck with your work

Comment: Ander, thanks for telling me - I'll do that in future.
Dan - Yes I'm working up to it but since I don't understand the code I'm still looking up the functions. Thanks for the help guys